# Display virtual keyword asp.net for password

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, virtual-keyboard

I have a login page with an input of type "password" I would like to have a virtual keyboard to enter the password. I've searched and I found the jquery script for virtual keyboard. The code said to add this to my page

```
$('input[type=password]').keyboard({
          layout: "qwerty",
          customLayout:
        [["q w e r t y {bksp}", "Q W E R T Y {bksp}"],
        ["s a m p l e {shift}", "S A M P L E {shift}"],
        ["{accept} {space} {cancel}", "{accept} {space} {cancel}"]]
      });
```

but I cant make it work!!!! nothing happens when I set focus on my password control.
Any suggestions?? thank you!! Nicole.

Comment: You might want to accept answers to your questions, to entice people to answer yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using  the [Virtual Keyboard Widget](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/virtual_keyboard) plugin.

1. Do you have a plugin script included? (jquery.keyboard.js)
2. Do you have the CSS scripts on your page?
3. Are you using jQuery version 1.3.x?
4. Do you have the jQuery UI included?